# OpenSuse 13.2 zypper does not work

Tags: linux, opensuse

I'm working on OpenSuse 13.2 and not that familiar with the OS. I have been trying to install a package via zypper,

```
sudo zypper python-rdkit
```

But I have got the following errors:

```
Repository 'packman' is invalid [packman|http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/packman/suse/13.2/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
```

So I went and checked the URL, and it actually didn't exist anymore. So I tried to update the packman repo first with the following command:

```
sudo zypper ar -f  http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_13.2/ packman
```

But I got an error saying, there is already a repo named packman. So I updated the code:

```
sudo zypper ar -f  http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_13.2/ packman2
```

It worked fine and I ran the following command,

```
sudo zypper -v ref
```

It failed for packman but worked for packman2 (saying up-to-date). But at the end, I got the following error:

```
File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/update/13.2/'
```

Similarly, I check the URL, and again it didn't work, and in the "http://download.opensuse.org/update/" URL, there is no folder for 13.2 and I am confused about what to do.

It will be a great help if you give me ideas.

Best!

Comment: 13.2 is no longer supported. Upgrade to leap.

Comment: OT: For current versions, try `zypper refresh -f` as root. (Adding this comment because this question is the top google result for the error message `'/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium` when restricting results to "last month".)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a currently supported version for which the software repositories are in the standard location, you will need to find copies of the repositories and configure the location manually. Under "EOL mirrors" on https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Mirrors you can find some candidate locations. You may also find copies elsewhere on the web. (The installer checks digital signatures so in principle you don't need to worry about the danger that somebody replaces a file with malware. However, for very old versions, the certificates may have expired.) There are many ways to tell openSUSE the new location of repositories. I prefer YaST2 --> Software --> Software Repositories.

Old installation repositories are easier to find than old update repositories. Unless you need to bring the installation to a specific patch level (for example to exactly reproduce a problem), 
I recommend that you simply disable the update repository that is currently configured. The system will be full of security issues anyway and you need to be careful what you do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the message

```
'/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium
```

when attempting `zypper dup` to upgrade from Leap 42.2 to Leap 42.3.  I fixed the issue in my case by changing in the `.repo` file the line

```
type=rpm-md
```

to

```
type=yast2
```